# How to remove control characters in decrypted .eml file with php like EOF, NUL, DLE

Tags: php, encryption, eml

I used the openssl_pkcs7_decrypt function to decrypt the encrypted .eml file. Now there are many control characters in the decrypted file like EOT, DLE, NUL ....

What is wrong or how can I remove these control characters?
Without removing the control characters I can't extract the content of the file via php.

I tried preg_replace('~[^\P{Cc}\r\n]+~u', '', $stream);
But nothing was removed.

Comment: You should've gotten back a file identical the plaintext file before encryption.

Comment: You are probably not encrypting/decrypting properly. As another commenter mentioned you should get back the exact same file and no need to do preg_replace